# Irreducible characters $\chi$ and normality of $\lbrace g\in G~|~\chi(g)=\lambda \chi(1)\rbrace$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of $G$. I need to show that if $\lambda$ is a $|G|$'th root of 1, then $\lbrace g\in G~|~\chi(g)=\lambda \chi(1)\rbrace\unlhd G$. Showing that this is true for $\lambda=1$ is not too difficult, we just need to realize this set as the kernel of the representation of $G$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module $GL(U)$. But I am having trouble showing this true for the general case. I was trying to find another homomorphism for which this set is the kernel of, but to no avail. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that since the character is invariant under conjugation, if $g$ is in this set then so is $hgh^{-1}$. Thus, the issue is to show that it is actually a subgroup, since then it will automatically be normal.

Comment: It is not in general going to be a subgroup. For one thing, it will not contain the identity.

Comment: I think the correct set should be $\{g : \chi(g) = \lambda\chi(1)$ for some $|G|$th root of unity $\}$.

Comment: @WSL That would make sense, as that can also be written as those with $|\chi(g)| = \chi(1)$, i.e. the center of the character.